# nav_msgs::Path without the field "pose"?

Tags: ros, nav-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I m trying to compile a code but I cannot do that since I m getting the following error:

```
error: ‘nav_msgs::Path_<std::allocator<void> >::_poses_type’ has no member named ‘pose’
```

But in the [API documentation](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseStamped.html) it is reported to have such field.
Furthermore I tried to echo another package not made by me and it outputs:

```
header: 
  seq: 25
  stamp: 
    secs: 1415216779
    nsecs: 703217309
  frame_id: map
poses: 
  - 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 1415216779
        nsecs: 703217309
      frame_id: map
    pose: 
      position: 
        x: 5.84004402161
        y: -0.0
        z: 0.0
      orientation: 
        x: 0.0
        y: 0.0
        z: 0.0
        w: 1.0
```

as you can see there is `poses` and `pose`.
In my CMakeLists.txt I have already enable to compile for nav_msgs too.
What could be?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196840/nav_msgs::path-without-the-field-%22pose%22-?!?!/) by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 893 on 2014-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

'Poses' is an array member of "Path" of type PoseStamped. Each PoseStamped has its own "pose" member (confusing, right?), so I think you should index it similar to the following:

```
some_path.poses[some_index].pose
```

http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Path.html

---

Originally posted by [BlitherPants](https://answers.ros.org/users/4967/blitherpants/) with karma: 504 on 2014-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-11-06**:
Thanks...the small square brakets were difficult to see.